# Trigger document copy to other folder on custom attribute change in BIM 360 Docs

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

I would like to automatically copy documents in a certain folder to another folder when one of the custom attributes of the item is set to a specific value.

Ideally it would happen in the background, triggered by the property change. But looking closer, it does not seem possible to get a webhook notification for an attribute change.

Or is it?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there's no event for changes on custom attributes.

[Here](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/webhooks/v1/reference/events/) you can find the list of supported events.

Maybe one of them can be used on your workflow (such as [version modified](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/webhooks/v1/reference/events/dm.version.modified/), for instance)